# Drawing SVG with Java script - no drawing

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have the following code

```
<div id="map-wrapper">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                         style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:0">
                        <path id="dotted-line"
                              stroke-dasharray="20,10"
                              fill="none" stroke="#F7C700" stroke-width="2px" />
                        <path id="animated-line"
                              stroke-dasharray="20,10"
                              fill="none" stroke="#793C25" stroke-width="4px" />
                    </svg>
  <div class="start"><span>Start Here</span></div>
  <div class="point one">
    <button>One</button>
  </div>
  <div class="point two">
    <button>Two</button>
  </div>
  <div class="point three">
    <button>Three</button>
  </div>
  <div class="point four">
    <button>Four</button>
  </div>
  <div class="point five">
    <button>Five</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n9szmw3g/ .

It doesn't work, I've copied the content from [here](http://ran.ge/2016/05/24/drawing-svgs-javascript-tutorial/).

What could I do to make it work ? I am newbie in svg and js.

Comment: if you'e using jQuery in your code, then you should import jQuery first. https://jsfiddle.net/n9szmw3g/1/

Comment: @Thomas yeah, i've missed adding jquery at the end of html file. Thank you guys for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SVG code works fine.

What is missing is a reference to jQuery which is used in the javascript code that you copied.

To get your jsFiddle working, you need to add jQuery to your project.

- click 'resources' in the 'Fiddle meta' menu to your left
- start typing 'jQuery'
- click the suggested library (currently 'jQuery 3.3.1')
- click the add icon (+)

Now jQuery is added to your project and the SVG is drawn in the output as expected.

When starting to work with javascript it's a great idea to get familiar with the browser console. It's an essential tool in troubleshooting, because it simply tells you when something went wrong.

Comment: Well, at the moment I have 3 files, a .css file, a .html file and a .js file, what I am missing is how do I add the jquery file to .html file in order to see it ?

Comment: Resolved. Thank you Johan. I've added the jquery at the end of file.

Comment: Great that you sorted it out!

If you want to add jQuery to your project outside jsFiddle add this to the `<head>` of your html document.

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

As instructed [here](http://code.jquery.com/)